# How to dynamically create class objects with serial naming?

Tags: java, object, dynamicobject

Suppose I take an integer user input - 17. Now I want to create 17 "Node" class objects. And they'll be named like node1, node2, ..., node17.

How to achieve that?

Comment: Why you want to do this?

Comment: Objects don't have names, unless they have a name attribute. Use a loop, create 17 Node instances, each with the desired name, and store them in a List<Node> or a Node[] array.

Comment: @JBNizet looks like he wants to create objects with reference names as node1, node2,...

Comment: What do you mean with _17 "Node" class objects_? 17 objects of class Node or 17 classes inheriting from Node?

Comment: If you really need to materialize the code for individual node variables consider [writing a code generator](http://pragmatictips.com/29) or use a [templating engine(like velocity)](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/05/05/cg-vel1.html) to do that more conveniently. But try to stick on the "conventional" methods like arrays or lists in this case.

Comment: @JBNizet I meant reference names.

Comment: Use an array or a List. That's exactly what they're for: storing 0 to N references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't. What you are asking is a bad idea.

What you can do is add multiple new objects to an Array or Collection.
If you don't care about names an `ArrayList<Node>` will do the job.
If you do need names then make them keys in a `HashMap<String, Node>` or similar.

```
public List<Node> makeThisManyNodes(int count) {
    List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        nodes.add(new Node());
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

---

```
static final String NODE_BASE_NAME = "node_%d";

public Map<String, Node> makeThisManyNodes(int count) {
    Map<String, Node> nodes = new HashMap<String, Node>();
    String key;
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        key = String.format(NODE_BASE_NAME, i);
        nodes.put(key, new Node());
    }
    return nodes;
}
```